# Fast Inserts Into Ordered Arrays

Tags: algorithm, sorting, binary-search

I am planning to implement binary search using arrays - however I also need to support dynamic updates / inserts into the array. The best approaches I've heard so far are in O(n) territory because all elements to the right of the insert point needs to be shifted to the right by one.

I pondered about this idea: I redefine / intercept (or "overload" depending on your language) the insertion method - if insertion into index 10 is detected for example, I "delay" this insertion, I keep the new element on a second list. Nothing is inserted in the real array, but the algorithm remembers the insertion point. Same for other insertions. Then if I detect an access to element 15, which I also intercept, I recalculate, offset the index by 1 to the right, and give the element 16 because there was an insertion into a location to the left of i=15.

Once in a while I would empty the second list by truly inserting them in the real list, possibly through insertion sort.

This sounds to me like it could work fast.

Would this be workable?

Thanks,

Comment: Although your question is not very clear, since mixing here several problems, IMO this could help you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree

Comment: AFAIK k-d trees do not seem to support fast dynamic inserts..

Comment: @user423805 You may want to clarify how your algorithm *remembers* the insertion points, how binary search handles the new, *delayed* insertions, and how you handle if there are N of such insertions for us to be able to analyze the complexity of the algorithm you propose.

Comment: What are the operations needing support? Will there be (inserts and) lookups by key, only? Is it necessary to know the next not greater/smaller? Do you need access by index?

Comment: All I need is  supporting insertion (any location), appending, searching I'd get for free due to the nature of the ordered array.

Comment: @ilim remembering insertion points is either through a second array, or a dictionary / hashmap.

Comment: @user423805 That is one way to *remember* them, yeah. But the challenge is, how are you going to take them into account in binary search? The inserted elements may have information on where they are inserted to in the original array. But the need to do that bookkeeping about both the original array and the delayed insertions in your binary search is what I believe will cost too much, resulting in a binary search less efficient than **O(logN)**.

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question. Why do you need an array? If you're doing many insertions as well as lookups, then a hash map or dictionary is a better fit if things don't need to be in sorted order. A skip list is a better solution if you have to keep things sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there's nothing really good in the direction you're looking.  I've done things like that in the past, but only when there was a known access pattern that made it efficient.

If you want to keep some of the efficiencies of array storage and binary search, while still allowing dynamic inserts, a B+ tree is a good tradeoff:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree

In a B+ tree, each node has an array of keys.  You choose the max length -- typically anywhere from 16 to 4096.  The array storage limits waste because you don't have a whole bunch of extra links, helps cache locality during searches, and provides a high fanout that limits depth of the tree.

Answer (score 1):

You did not clarify some critical information about your idea such as how your algorithm *remembers* the insertion points of the newly inserted values, how binary search handles the new(i.e. delayed) insertions, and how you handle if there are N of such insertions.

In any case, you would either have to merge the delayed inserts with the original array at some point, which would take **O(N)** time, or you would have to run binary search taking into account both the original array and the *waiting list* of new inserts. And considering dynamic inserts could cause inserting an element between two elements that are themselves in that secondary array, I am not sure how you could even do that in a systematic manner. You are likely to compromise from the access cost to any element of A, which is **O(1)** in a regular array, and in turn may end up having a binary search that is less efficient than **O(logN)**. So, a high-level overview of the incomplete definition of your idea seems not likely to achieve the desired results in terms of complexity.

By its definition binary search works on an *ordered* container and arrays storing each element consecutively) makes impossible any attempts to insert *at any position* and then rearrange the order in less than **O(N)** in the worst case.

Although this is not a formal proof, intuitively, you may think of this case. Whenever you have to insert to an array A an element that is smaller than all the elements present in A, for a future binary search operation to be able to work on A, you have to insert it in the beginning, in order to keep A ordered. And when you insert such a small element in the first position of A, you have to shift all the present elements in A to the right by 1, which is **O(N)**, if size of A is considered to be N. (See similar procedure in the insertion step of the well-known algorithm [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort))

So, unless you change your preference about using an array, you are stuck with that **O(N)** time complexity bound when inserting to it. However, if you consider using a balanced binary search tree (e.g. [Red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), [AVL tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree)) you may achieve faster average-time complexity for insertion and you do not sacrifice your efficiency of searching for an element. Granted, in that case, the algorithm you are running to find an element will be more of a tree traversal than a binary search. Still, if more efficient search and insertion(and removal) operations are more important to you than the specific algorithms and data structures you use, then making this change in your data structure and algorithm preferences should be tolerable.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can always use double-linked lists and in this way make re-sorting unneeded.

Comment: If doubly-linked lists were used, binary search complexity would increase quite a bit, as access time to an element would take longer than **O(1)**, possibly **O(N)**. Although it is possible, I doubt that increasing the complexity of binary search to **O(NlogN)** or something similar would be the desired behavior.

Comment: Complexity: Of course not, because you would NOT be using the index of the array but that of the LINKED list. The only potential issue is loosing the whole thing if the links are broken, in which case it would be easy to re-construct using the array index.

Comment: @FDavidov Did not quite understand how you will juggle and handle the indices to achieve **O(logN)** time complexity. In any event, the focus of my response was to explain why there is a worst case cost of **O(N)** when trying to make "dynamic" insertions, as the author put it, and to state that better time complexities were possible only when the data structure and the algorithm was changed.

Comment: @ilim wouldn't a linked list stored with sequential memory address give a better time complexity?

Comment: @PrathikRajendranM Not sure how usage of linked list in a sequential memory address can help dividing the *list* into two, especially once the links are updated and are not sequential. I believe access cost would eventually be higher than O(1), or at least maintaining  O(1) access after each insertion would add some complexity higher than O(logN), which would affect either the insertion of the binary search depending on your implementation.

Comment: @ilim, imagine that you have an array of structures with three elements: Value, Previous, Next, and that this list has, say, 100 elements initially sorted (and hence "Previous" and "Next" indices follow the same sequence as the array). Now, you need to insert a new element. You deploy it in position 101 of the array but then find the correct location using the "Previous" and "Next" indices. Once you find it, you update these fields in array location 101 as well as in the corresponding existing elements. What takes time is finding the location, not updating pointers.

Comment: @ilim, my above suggestion does increase complexity, but it spares you re-sorting every time and hence you should be in a better position I believe.

Comment: @FDavidov As you adequately put, finding the location (i.e. traversing the list) has **O(N)** time complexity, increasing the insertion cost to a complexity the author did not want, adding an overhead of pointers to keep track of. Again, it is a viable option, but the access cost increasing from O(1) to O(N) in a linked list is what is bounding your alternative in terms of efficiency.

Comment: @FDavidov Perhaps I stated something incorrectly in my response. I did not mean that you have to make the effort to sort the array from scratch each time. What I had in mind was something similar to the insertion step in [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), which has O(N) worst case time complexity and which is not unlike what you do in your solution using a linked list.

Comment: OK, now I got your point. Thanks for your clarification. There is another method (please don't ask me for its name as I only remember the idea): I would call it a two-dimensional hashing. This method, however, strongly depends on your up-front knowledge of Min and Max value you may receive, and that the distribution of values is rather homogeneous across the whole range.

Comment: @FDavidov You're welcome. I am sure some complex methods or data structures exist that may help achieve a similar efficiency. But like I said, I just wanted to underline why it's not possible to overcome the time cost bound when an array is used, and to provide one example idea to achieve better time complexity for insertion and find.

Answer (score 1):

"Would this be workable?": maybe, but it is unlikely.

For every insertion, you will have to lookup the list of pending insertions and determine the correction to the insertion point. And you will have to insert the new key in the pending list. You are back to the original problem of insertion in an ordered array, with a smaller array.

If you count the insertions, assuming pending lists of maximum size L, you will perform O(N) of them, for a total cost of O(N.L). So you need L to be better than O(1).

If you count the merges, you will perform N/L of them, with a cost N/L.(N + L). Then you need L to be Ω(N).

These two requirements do not seem compatible.

---

Be sure that the problem of insertion in a sorted list has been thoroughly investigated before you (probably before you were born), and no suitable solution based on a pending list has been adopted.

On the opposite, balanced search trees are universally used for the purpose of dynamic sorting, and they are known to be optimal, with a bound of O(Log N) for search, insertion and deletion operations.

Comment: I don't want to overburden the question with these extras, but the reason I wanted to use arrays was so that I would have straight-forward implementation of n-nearest neighbor; finding nearest on ordered array was simple, nearest n would be items around it. I did not see any O(log N) n-nearest neighbor implementation on binary search trees (except on a few dinky web pages), Sedgewick has nothing on it, that's why I went to this direction. But yeah - I'd prefer using BSTs, absolutely.